# Why does my chrysanthemum plant cannot tolerate mild direct sunlight?

Tags: leaves, sunlight, chrysanthemum, stress

[image]

I purchased chrysanthemum plant from a nursery store 3 days ago. However, when I keep my plant under direct sunlight the leaves starts drooping as you can see in the picture. Since its winter time, the sunlight isn't harsh and the weather is moderate around 60-80 degrees fahrenheit. When I move the plant indoors the leaves starts recovering. Does chrysanthemum hates direct sunlight or is there something else which is causing the plant to stress out?